# How to achieve the following with LINQ multiple GroupBy

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, grouping

I am using following two functions to achieve dynamic nested GroupBy:

```
    public static IEnumerable<GroupResult<TElement>> GroupByMany<TElement>(this IEnumerable<TElement> elements, params string[] groupSelectors)
    {

        var selectors =
            new List<Func<TElement, object>>(groupSelectors.Length);

        foreach (var selector in groupSelectors)
        {
            LambdaExpression l = dyn.DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(typeof(TElement), typeof(object), selector);
            selectors.Add((Func<TElement, object>)l.Compile());
        }

        return elements.GroupByMany(selectors.ToArray());

    }

    public static IEnumerable<GroupResult<TElement>> GroupByMany<TElement>(this IEnumerable<TElement> elements, params Func<TElement, object>[] groupSelectors)
    {
        if (elements.Count() > 0 && groupSelectors.Length > 0)
        {
            var selector = groupSelectors.First();

            //reduce the list recursively until zero

            var nextSelectors = groupSelectors.Skip(1).ToArray();

            return
                elements.GroupBy(selector).Select(
                    g => new GroupResult<TElement>
                    {
                        Key = g.Key ?? "(none)",
                        Count = g.Count(),
                        Items = g,
                        SubGroups = g.GroupByMany(nextSelectors)
                    });
        }
        else
            return null;
    }
```

This generates a nested structure of the GroupResult type:

```
public class GroupResult<T>

{
    public object Key { get; set; }

    public int Count { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<T> Items { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<GroupResult<T>> SubGroups { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()

    { return string.Format("{0} ({1})", Key, Count); }

}
```

An example of some items grouped this way are below:

> **World**
>        **Europe**
>             **France**
>                 Camera (incl. HD remotely operated motion activated)
>             **France**
>                  Camera (incl. HD remotely operated motion activated)
>           **Spain**
>                Patrol Car

What I would like to achieve is the following:

> **World**
>        **Europe**
>             **France**
>                 Camera (incl. HD remotely operated motion activated)
>                  Camera (incl. HD remotely operated motion activated)
>           **Spain**
>                Patrol Car

In **bold** there is Key property of the GroupResult class.

Any ideas how to achieve this join by Key on the lowest level?